# In R, add commas at right place in string of number

Tags: r, string

We are looking to convert a long list of numbers into a currency format with dollar signs and commas. Convert `c(10392, 3928403)` into `c('$10,392', '$3,928,403')`. Adding the `$` is easy but we are struggling to automate the adding of commas into the strings in the right locations (thousands separators). Is this possible in R?

We have:

```
> paste0('$', c(10392, 3928403))
[1] "$10392"   "$3928403"
```

Comment: There is `comma` function in `scales` or `formattable` or `dollar_format`

Comment: What about `scales::dollar_format()(c(10392, 3928403))#[1] "$10,392"    "$3,928,403"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution:

(Similar to @akrun's suggestions.)

```r
scales::dollar(c(10392, 3928403))

#> [1] "$10,392"    "$3,928,403"
```

Comment: `dollar` is better than the one I suggested.